# Temporary Persistence when Dealing with MVC and Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, persistence

Perhaps it is my lack of experience still with really stretching MVC and Entity Framework but I've run into a problem I can't really figure out.

Up until now my applications have been simple: I show and hide a few divs in a View, and when the user has entered all data they hit submit and I save it to the database using EF. The complication I have now is I have basically have to have a flow where:

Person Registers -> Register Another Person? If Yes -> Person Registers -> And So On...

EDIT* To Clarify: Person comes in to Register a group of people. The first screen is a form where they enter identification info, next is clicked, and then They are asked if they'd like to add someone else, if they click yes they repeat that process. I create a Registration Object each time this happens until they don't want to add anymore, after which they are directed to a "Confirmation" action that shows them their registrations and let's them submit their registrations.

I need to have a way to temporarily hold that data while the user jumps to different actions and ultimately submits it to be saved. I'd prefer not to hold a bunch of models in a Session variable.

Comment: Could you perhas elucidate on what you expect to happen during the person registers --> register another, etc. process? The proposed solution depends really on what you want to happen. You could use AJAX to persist to the database the data for each 'register' event. Alternatively, you could just have a 'registration confirmed' page offer up the 'register another' option with an action link back to the rame registration page. Lots of possibilities! Perhaps being a little more descriptive/specific would give respondants more to go on

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your given example, you shouldn't be holding on to anything. After each person is registered, that data can be saved to the database immediately before redirecting back to the form to allow the user to register another person. At each step, you're dealing with a discrete unit, so there's no reason not to just save it immediately.

In a different scenario, perhaps something like a wizard, where you collect partial info in multiple steps, which culminate to produce one discrete unit, your only real option is to use something like `TempData`. `TempData` is still session-based, and uses the `Session` object under the hood, but it does have the advantage over traditional use of `Session` that the data is only persisted through the next request, whereas `Session` data is persisted for the life of the session, which can be anywhere from minutes to weeks based on configuration.

Comment: They are registering as a group. I don't want someone to come in and half way through registering 5 people decide they don't want to register anyone anymore, and having junk in the Table.

Comment: So is there no way to add these to a DbSet without saving them, that way they are persisted between actions? I've never tried this so I don't know if it would work.

Comment: For something like that, you'll need to use `TempData` or a JavaScript solution on the front end to dynamically add additional persons to a single form so you can just post everything at once. The latter choice is actually probably the best for something like this. However, no you can't add something to a DbSet without saving. The DbSet itself is not persisted; it's just a repository tying the entities to the database table they represent. Adding something to DbSet indicates that you intend to save it to the database, but if you don't call `SaveChanges()`, it just goes away.

Comment: I'm curious about the second option you mentioned regarding using Javascript. Could you elaborate on that a bit more?